# StrToTime Doesn't work when passing a variable in

Tags: php

So I have an array of dates like this -

**Contents of $monthsArray**

```
    2015-02-01
    2015-03-01
    2015-04-01
    2015-05-01
    2015-06-01
    2015-07-01
    2015-08-01
    2015-09-01
    2015-10-01
```

I want to loop through the array and minus one year from each date -

```
foreach ($monthsArray as $month)
{
$ytdFrom = date("$month", strtotime('-1 year'));
$ytdTo = $month;
}
```

The value from the first loop of **$ytdFrom is still = 2015-02-01**, and so on, the ytdFrom doesn't minus the one year.

Although If run the following code -

```
$ytdFrom= date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 year')); // Todays date 2016-02-01
```

**This would = 2015-02-01.**

I can't see why this is happening, strToTime requires a string as its parameter and that is exactly what I'm passing in.

Any Ideas?

Comment: edited... $month is a value from the $monthArray

Comment: So that is where you want the `strtotime` to start from?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean..

Comment: date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year', $month))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date` function first takes the format you want it to output the string from, then the date you want formatted. `strtotime` takes the time you wanted formatted and an optional second parameter for the time the function should start from (unix timestamp). If not specified it is the current time. So for a demo:

```
echo date('y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year', strtotime('2015-03-01')));
```

Outputs:

```
14-03-01
```

Because it is one year before `2015-03-01`.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/511126

Where as,

```
echo date('y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year'));
```

outputs as `15-02-01`. because that is `1 year` before today.

...so to conclude you'd really want:

```
echo date('y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year', strtotime($month)));
```

and modify the `date` values to whatever format you want; http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Comment: Works great, obviously I have misunderstood the function! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, problem is that `strtotime` returns value based from actual time. This is, why `strtotime('-1 year')` returns `2015-02-01`.

But you need substract some interval from your date, and for that is this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sub.php.

From my point of view is best way to do this with `DateTime` object (but you still can use procedural style like `date_*`), like this:

```
(new DateTime('2016-02-01'))
     ->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 year'))
     ->format('Y-m-d');
```